# Injecting Stateful Bean inside Stateless bean

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, jndi, stateful-session-bean, stateless-session

When injecting a `stateful session bean` inside a `stateless session bean` using `DI`, what happens exactly:
Did the container inject a new instance of stateful bean for every stateless bean (which exists in a pool), or it is the same instance shared between them?

Why it is indicated that using `JNDI` in this case is better than DI?

I really didn't get that.

Answer (score 1):

For each session the @Statefull will be new instance.
@Statefull isn't a direct instance, it's a proxy and can be changed every time when is needed even inside @Stateless

Answer (score 0):

Basically it doesn't make sense to inject stateful into stateless, because that stateful will be shared by many clients, if they happen to get same stateless instance, or one client can also access different stateful instances, if it access different stateless instances.

Using JNDI or not, doesn't make any difference in this case. Stateful cannot be shared by many clients and each statelss instance is a different client. If you will use JNDI then depending where you do the lookup you can end up with new stateful instance with every call to the stateless.

Any reason why would you like to inject stateful in stateless?